# Backbone.js: Existing View events continue to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

In my View, I have events that fire `onclick` of an A element. Unfortunately, when I create a new View from a Model, the existing events of first Model/View pair continue to fire. What ends up happening is the `save()` continues to use the existing Model instead of the new one and I can never create a new Model and use that Model without refreshing the page. I'm very new to backbone.js, but is there a way to `save()` that existing Model but remove its View? If I'm not making sense, please let me know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much.

```
$(function() {

var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        begun: false,
        currentPlayer: 1
    },

    play: function() {
        console.log(this.id);
        var player = (this.get('currentPlayer') == 1) ? 2 : 1;
        this.save({ 'currentPlayer': player, 'begun': true });
    }

});

var GameList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Game,

    localStorage: new Store('game'),

    existing: function() {
        return this.filter(function(game){ return game.get('begun'); });
    },

    unused: function() {
        return this.filter(function(game){ return !game.get('begun'); });
    }

});

var Games = new GameList;

var GameView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#board'),

    events: {
        'click li a': 'play'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'clear');
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.clear);
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log(this.model.id);
        this.clear();
    },

    clear: function() {
        this.el.find('li a span').html('');
    },

    play: function(event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).find('span').html(this.model.get('currentPlayer'));
        this.model.play();
        return false;
    }

});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#info'),

    events: {
        'click #new-game': 'newGame'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'startGame', 'getGame');
        Games.bind('add', this.startGame);
        Games.bind('reset', this.getGame);

        Games.fetch();
    },

    newGame: function(event) {
        Games.create();
        return false;
    },

    getGame: function() {
        var existing = Games.existing();
        var unused = Games.unused();
        if(existing.length) this.startGame(existing[0]);
        else if(unused.length) this.startGame(unused[0]);
        else Games.create();
    },

    startGame: function(game) {
        var view = new GameView({ model: game });
        view.render();
    }

});

var App = new AppView;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only ever one instance of a model.  You can have many views of the same model.  When one view expires, just remove it from the DOM.

```
$(this.el).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Events in Backbone view are [delegated](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-event-delegation-in-4-minutes/). In your case this means that click on every element that matches `'#board li a'` selector will fire the `'play'` method. Since you are using the same element for every game view (`'#board'`), every click on `'li a'` inside it will trigger all `'play'` methods of all game views, thus saving all the models.

So, if you can have multiple game views on your page, use separate element for each of them (just remove `el: $('#board')` from your view declaration and append created view manually to `'#board'`.

Or, if you can have only one game view, override a `remove` method of your view to undelegate all events from `'#board'` and call `remove()` every time before creating a new game view:

```
remove: function() {
    this.$el.off().remove()
}
```